# "which is what I did" vs "which was what I did"

Tags: grammar, tense

The following passage is in the first-person past-tense narrative:

> I decided to find out more about murder cases, which
>   **is/was** what I did for the next couple of years.

Is is or was the correct option in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Here you should use "was", not "is" because you're writing in the past tense. Moreover, instead of saying "in the next couple of years" you should say: "in the last couple of years". I hope this is more clear for you now.

Comment: "In the last couple of years" is not what he is saying here. He is talking about a point in the past, and going forward a number of years from that point.

Comment: Also, I would say "is" is correct as well, since the past tense is already covered by "what I did". I'm not a native speaker though.

Comment: So if he is talking about the present, maybe it's better to say: "which was what I did and I'll keep doing for the next couple of years" something like that, I think that this will sound better.